# Github Actions SSH - pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

i am trying connect to ssh via github runner. But i am still getting this error.

> pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

I have already set up the private key & known_hosts

```
name: deploy
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Dpeloy'
        type: string
        default: 'Deploy'
        required: true
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      
      - name: Install SSH Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          known_hosts: 'just-a-placeholder-so-we-dont-get-errors'
          
      - name: Adding Known Hosts
        run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  
  - name: Connect to server
    run: "ssh root@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}"
    
  - name: Test
    run: "cd /var/www/test"
```

My server is **not** running in docker.

Can anyone explain me this error, and possible solution? Thank you

Also github actions workflow and error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub runner will not allow you to connect to another server and execute the next WF steps in the context of the SSH connection.

Try using the [ssh-action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action), for example. It allows executing remote ssh commands and you can run any commands on your server.

```
- name: executing remote ssh commands using ssh key
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
    script: cd /var/www/test
```

Also, there is a possibility to run multiple commands:

```
- name: multiple command
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
    script: |
      cd /var/www/test
      ls -al
```

Please read the full [options list](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action#input-variables) to properly configure it (keys, known hosts).